# Word for Pretentiously Academic but Useless

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that incorporates all, or most, of the following (when referring to a sentence or a piece of technical literature):

- Highly academic
- Not useful (despite being technically correct)
- Overly verbose/eloquent
- Superfluous (to be honest, this seems to incorporate the rest, but I want to see if there is a better word here)

Sample sentence (I hear it's required):

> There are many ____ white-paper definitions which only serve to
>   dazzle the reader with the
>   author's purported intelligence.

Comment: I propose the word **sufflatoriate** (verb and adjective) whose meanings you will have to educe for yourself.

Comment: Serving as a noun or adjective, [pseudointellectual](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pseudointellectual) might fit the bill. From Wiktionary: (Noun) A person who claims proficiency in scholarly or artistic activities while lacking in-depth knowledge or critical understanding.

Comment: I can get my head around *overly verbose*, but *overly **eloquent**?* It seems to me OP is just indulging his [anti-intellectualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-intellectualism) *(commonly expressed as deprecation of education and philosophy or dismissal of art, literature, and science as impractical and even contemptible human pursuits)*. So we should probably avoid "erudite, difficult" terms here and go for things like ***clever-clogs*** and ***smarty-pants***.

Comment: I agree with FumbleFingers. The word used in this context should avoid sounding equally pretentious as the person it is supposed to describe. Maybe "fancypants" or something like it.

Comment: **MODERATOR NOTE:** Answers should consist mostly of your own words. [If a question solicits nothing but copypasta, it should be closed](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160/2085).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The two most common, apart from Lux's *pretentious*, are going to be

## [pedantic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pedantic)

> 1. in the manner of a [pedant](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pedant), *hence*
>
>    > a. excessively concerned with minutiae. 
>    >     b. needlessly displaying academic learning.

and

## [pompous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pompous)

> 1. (*originally*) characterized by [pomp](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pomp) and splendor.
> 2. (*now the primary sense*) affectedly solemn and self-important.

You'd use the first if the important aspect was how unimportant the information being shared was, the later if you wanted to emphasize the (undeserved) self-importance with which it was being shared.

Since scholars have been writing for ages and this kind of behavior was, if anything, *more* common during the era when all scholars were monks, there are absolute scads of synonyms for variants and subvarieties. Some, like *precious*, could be considered gendered slurs; others, like *bookish* or *nerdy*, may not be taken as negative at all in our present culture. Two of my favorites are *[mumpsimus](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mumpsimus)* and *sumpsimus*.

Answer (score 29):

> **sententious**
>   *adjective /senˈten.ʃəs/*
>   trying to appear wise, intelligent, and important, in a way that is annoying:
>     *The document was sententious and pompous.*
>    --[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sententious?a=british)

The word signifies the thoughtless serial quotation of distilled wisdom that would only be wise in the correct context, but not when parroted as a received opinion by someone oblivious to the quotations' actual meaning and scope.

In the same way, by extension, the term may be applied to the careless quotation of scientific truths, engineering practices, or legal maxims, when used to support propositions for which those truths are either wholly irrelevant, or perhaps only relevant by way of unintended (and unrecognized) irony.

*Sententious* also has non-pejorative usages, but those are not so relevant to this question.

Answer (score 10):

The OP does not make clear whether the 'learned' author is writing 'in an ivory tower' (i.e. unaware that their language is difficult for 'ordinary' people to follow) or, whether the 'learned' author is intentionally trying to impress/show-off.

In the former case, where the brilliant scholar is writing honestly and simply to express ideas as best they can, words that could serve the sample sentence are:

***Arcane*** -  Hidden, concealed, secret (OED). Often used of knowledge.

***Abstruse*** - Difficult to understand; obscure, recondite (OED).

***Recondite*** - Esp. of a subject of study or discussion: little known or understood; abstruse, obscure; profound (OED)

In situations where the learned author is intentionally trying to show-off/impress then words described in other answers here - ***pompous***, ***sententious***, ***pretentious*** and especially ***pedantic*** (*exaggeratedly or absurdly learned*, OED) - probably fit better.

Comment: Please consider your “answer” — and perhaps this question itself — in light of this post from one of Stack Exchange’s Community Managers (an employee) on [Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160/2085). You might also consider our Help Center’s directions on [how to reference material written by others](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) in posts that should be mainly your own words rather than copypasta.

Comment: @tchrist - a fair cop.  Thanks for the interesting links.  I'm inclined to agree with Martha (first answer to first link) - SWR are often an interesting challenge.  But I do agree too that answers like my first effort here are dull.

Answer (score 9):

Might I humbly suggest:

**[esoteric](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/esoteric?s=t)** ˌɛsəˈtɛrɪk,ˌiːsəˈtɛrɪk; adjective

intended for or likely to be understood by only a small number of people with a specialized knowledge or interest.

-OR-

**[grandiloquent](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/grandiloquent)** ɡranˈdɪləkwənt; adjective 

pompous or extravagant in language, style, or manner, especially in a way that is intended to impress.

*Personal note: Neither quite fulfill the "not useful" condition. Personally speaking, I think "arcane" could work, if one tries to not automatically think of dragon summoning and all that fantasy stuff.

Source: Both from Dictionary.com. Click on the words to link through.

Answer (score 8):

**fustian**

adjective

3. cheap; worthless
4. pompous; bombastic

   [Look it up here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fustian)

Comment: Bonus points if the scholarship concerns 'Orientalism' or the Middle East.

Comment: Native speaker here (American) and I've *never* heard that word...who would even use that? Its so hoity toity and over the top ...oh, ....wait. ..,

Comment: Heh. Defining ‘fustian’ with ‘bombastic’ is quite neat little inside joke.

Comment: @BruceWayne: It is used all the time here in New York, especially among the lower classes. "Brachiate" and "perspicacious" are also popular.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Yes, it is. That dictionary dude is quite the wit.

Comment: @Ricky In my neck of the woods, the lower classes swear by _lexiphanic_ instead.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Wow. I'll bet it has't been used anywhere along the East Coast since at least the Treaty of Paris ... by anyone ... except Trump and his posse of ancient Greek scholars, maybe ...

Comment: This is copypasta, not an answer. Answers should consist mostly of your own words. If a question solicits nothing but copypasta, it should be closed.

Answer (score 5):

You may also consider ***convoluted***.

> There are many ***convoluted*** white-paper definitions which just
> serve to confuse the reader in a vain attempt to dazzle the reader
> with the author's purported intelligence.

ODO:

> **[convoluted](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/convoluted)**
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** (especially of an argument, story, or sentence) extremely complex and difficult to follow.
> ‘its convoluted narrative
> encompasses all manner of digressions’
>
> ‘This is the kind of convoluted wording that pops up on a regular
> basis, and my head still hurts trying to untangle it.’

Comment: I would suggest convoluted as I think the current definition of the word has drifted from the dictionary definitions to mean something like "unnecessarily complicating a simple subject in a way that doesn't ultimately make any sense" (that isn't the dictionary definition though). It does not necessarily carry the tone of "academic" either. Still, I think it is BETTER than some of the answers as it more strongly suggests a flawed approach

Answer (score 5):

Funnily enough…

> ## [***academic***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/academic)
>
> adj. not of practical relevance; of only theoretical interest.

<sup>(from Oxford Dictionaries Online)</sup>

I think it's clear where this meaning came from!

> A further discussion on this point would be academic.

Comment: Please edit your post to conform with [the network-wide guidelines of how to reference others’ work](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) which you've copypasta’d in here.

Comment: I've fixed that for you: you need to include as plain text the source of your citation because our licence allows the content to be reproduced as plain text without hyperlinks.

Answer (score 4):

I think the word "**turgid**" could fit nicely here. From Google:

turgid
ˈtəːdʒɪd
adjective

1.
swollen and distended or congested.
"a turgid and fast-moving river"
synonyms:   swollen, congested; More

2.
(of language or style) tediously pompous or bombastic.
"some turgid verses on the death of Prince Albert"
synonyms:   bombastic, pompous, overblown, overripe, inflated, high-flown, affected, pretentious, grandiose, florid, flowery, ornate, magniloquent, grandiloquent, rhetorical, oratorical, orotund; More

Comment: "Google" is not an acceptable reference on ELU.

Comment: Apparently google uses [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com).

Comment: I checked ODO and even Merriam Webster but neither matched the one from google and I couldn't find the source on Google itself. And this appeared above the search bar and not on a link from Google so I included Google as the source.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think mine is as good as some of the other answers out there, but I figured I should offer some more options.

[sesquipedalian](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sesquipedalian)

> given to using long words

[gnostic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gnostic)

> possessing knowledge, especially esoteric knowledge of spiritual matters

[jargony](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/jargon)/jargonistic

The noun form (jargon) has these definitions:

> 1.
>   the language, especially the vocabulary, peculiar to a particular trade, profession, or group:
>   medical jargon.
>
> 2.
>   unintelligible or meaningless talk or writing; gibberish.

Answer (score 2):

The correct word is **Fustian**:

*2. An inflated style of writing; a kind of writing in which high-sounding words are used, above the dignity of the thoughts or subject; bombast.
[1913 Webster]
Claudius . . . has run his description into the most wretched fustian. Addison.
[1913 Webster]*

[Source](http://gcide.gnu.org.ua/?q=fustian&define=Define&strategy=.)

More than just bombastic, the word denotes the use of the unnecessary elevated style of writing without a useful purpose.

Answer (score 1):

[rhetorical](https://www.google.com/search?q=rhetorical%20definition&oq=rh&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i59j0l3.1405j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

> expressed in terms intended to persuade or impress.

[loquacious](https://www.google.com/search?q=loquacious%20definition&oq=loquacious%20d&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l4.8818j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

> tending to talk a great deal; talkative.

[grandiloquent](https://www.google.com/search?q=grandiloquent%20definition&oq=grandiloque&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i67k1j0j0i67k1j0l7.46628.49174.0.50099.11.11.0.0.0.0.145.967.8j2.10.0....0...1.1.64.serp..1.10.967...35i39k1j0i10i46k1j46i10k1.sNlBqZf22cI)

> pompous or extravagant in language, style, or manner, especially in a way that is intended to impress.

[magniloquent](https://www.google.com/search?q=magniloquent%20definition&oq=magnilo%20definition&gs_l=serp.3.1.0i13k1j0i7i30k1l3j0i8i7i30k1l2j0i13i30k1l4.32274.34318.0.36362.7.7.0.0.0.0.532.1062.3j2j5-1.6.0....0...1.1.64.serp..1.6.1061...0i7i10i30k1.HLoB8bBe3jE)

> using high-flown or bombastic language.

Comment: I think none of these do it - rhetorical doesn't cover the "overly verbose" aspect, equivocal is not what I am looking for, and the other three probably shouldn't be used while accusing someone of being superfluous/pretentious. I appreciate the reply though.

Comment: Sorry I edited the equivocal. My mistake. Removed it. I meant equivocation but it doesn't work well in your example sentence and doesn't have a great adjective form to use. I'll find some others.

Comment: Pompous, pleonasm, tautology, circumlocution? Anything like that?

Comment: I think pedantic is what I wanted, thanks for the help though, really. Pompous is close, but doesn't indicate being overly academic. The other's are not colloquial.

Comment: This is copypasta, not an answer. Answers should consist mostly of your own words. If a question solicits nothing but copypasta, it should be closed.

Comment: @tchrist I wasn't familiar with the euphemism "copypasta" but I obviously gather its meaning now. Are these not all copypasta answers here then? Should we simply not answer? I ask because I have tried using my own words but people then groaned about not using dictionary sources and citations. Please give some guidance on that if you will? Thanks.

Comment: This has been discussed repeatedly, including by the powers that be [as shown here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160/2085), but we as a site have never done enough to crack down on it. I can see we need still more discussion, alas.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for the link. I'll read it. I honestly just need some guidance on what is acceptable answering. I see so, so many that are these types of answers. I'm just trying to be helpful. But I do want to make the site as succinct and efficient as possible per the sites rules/goals. I hope you understand my intentions. My goal is to be useful and helpful to the community.

Answer (score 0):

The word that first came to my mind is **[ponderous](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ponderous)**, which conveys the verbosity and academical nature of a work

> 1. of great weight; heavy; massive.
> 2. dull and labored: a ponderous dissertation.

Or perhaps **[heavy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/heavy)**, which can typically refer to any kind of text which is hard to read

> 6. of major import; grave; serious: a heavy offense.
> 7. deep or intense; profound: a heavy thinker; heavy slumber.